# Javascript listen two events and fire one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I listen for two distinct events and only when all two events are detected fire a function?

Comment: it would help to know which two events you are interested in

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for Promises... once you've wrapped the event in a Promise, `Promise.all` is your friend. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functions are created:

```
    var got = { first : 0, second : 0 };
    function fire(event_type)
    {
      got[ event_type ] = 1;
      if( got.first && got.second )
      {
        //do stuff and reset
         got = { first : 0, second : 0 };
      }
    }
```

This is the listener part:

```
    document.onclick=function (){fire('first');}
    document.onmouseover=function (){fire('second');}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is where [Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) excel:

```
var prom1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    $("foo").one("someEvent", resolve);
});
var prom2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    $("bar").one("otherEvent", resolve);
});
Promise.all([prom1, prom2]).then(function(){
    //woo!
});
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it, compared to other hacky solutions trying to reinvent the wheel. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Detect them both, record when you've received one, and check to see if the other has already been received (which means BOTH have been received).  Remember to "forget" about them when this happens.

Answer (score 1):

You have many options.

For example: (without using any library)

```
(function(){
a=false; b=false;
function doIt(){
alert('both function have fired')
}
document.onclick=function (){a=true;if(a&&b) doIt()}
document.onmouseout=function (){b=true;if(a&&b) doIt()}

})()
```

JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3nDds/
You need to click inside the document, and move out the document.

Comment: What if I click multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the data attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/vpA3A/3/

```
$("#mybutton").on("mouseover", function(event) {
    var $button = $(this);
    $button.data("mouse", true);
    dowork($button);
}).on("click", function(event) {
    var $button = $(this);
    $button.data("click", true);
    dowork($button);
});

function dowork($button)
{
    if($button.data("mouse") == true && $button.data("click") == true) {
        alert('both events');
        $button.data('mouse', false).data('click', false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If it's two states place the function calls inside each other after the first event listener.